# Saving a uint8_t ciphertext into DataModel

Tags: iphone, rsa, public-key-encryption, xcdatamodel

I am building a simple iphone (SDK6.1) application that encrypts some user's notes, stores the into a database and when user enters a password (does not need to be encrypted) it will decrypt his notes and show them to him.

For the database i am using [Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/Articles/cdBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001650-TP1) (.xcdatamodel). The encrypted text at the moment is declared as String in the data model and in the Notes.h fil,e it is declared as NSString.

For the Encryption i am using apple's sample code from CryptoExercise which works perfectly.

The problem is that when i try to save the encrypted text in the database and then decrypt it i am not getting the desired results.. basically i am getting an empty string back.

Obviously i am using the following code to convert from uint8_t to NSString so i can store it into the data model and i understand that this is my main problem.

```
uint8_t *cipherBuffer = NULL;
SecKey *encrypt = [[SecKey alloc]init];
NSString *et = [[NSString alloc]init];

[encrypt generateKeyPairRSA];

// Encrypt the plain text
cipherBuffer = [encrypt Encryption:plainTextField.text];

// Convert uint8_t to NSString
NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
[data appendBytes:cipherBuffer length:strlen((char*)cipherBuffer)+1];
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];

// Save to Data Model
[self.currentNote setEncryptedText:string];
[self.delegate addNewNoteViewControllerDidSave];
// Retrieve encrypted text from database
et = [self.currentNote encryptedText];

// Convert back to uint_8
NSData *someData = [et dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
const void *bytes = [someData bytes];
uint8_t *crypto_data = (uint8_t*)bytes;

// Decrypt Data
[encrypt Decryption:crypto_data];
```

As i said before i understand that converting uint8_t is the main problem here and i would like to know which is the correct way to do this?

Is it possible with Data Model at all, or should i go to SQLite??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So just to answer the question so i can use code and everything..

I changed the EncryptedText in the Data Model to Binary Data and then the code would look like this:

```
uint8_t *cipherBuffer = NULL;
SecKey *encrypt = [[SecKey alloc]init];

[encrypt generateKeyPairRSA];

cipherBuffer = [encrypt Encryption:plainTextField.text];

NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
[data appendBytes:cipherBuffer length:strlen((char*)cipherBuffer)+1];

// Save cipher into the Data Model
[self.currentNote setEncryptedText:data];
[self.delegate addNewNoteViewControllerDidSave];

// Retrieve cipher back from Data Model
NSData *etData = [[NSData alloc]init];
etData = [self.currentNote encryptedText];

// Convert back to uint8_t
const void *bytes = [etData bytes];
uint8_t *crypto_data = (uint8_t*)bytes;

// De cypher
[encrypt Decryption:crypto_data];
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot convert arbitrary bytes sequences to `NSString` and back like that. For example,
if `data` contains the single byte `128` (hex `0x80`), then

```
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

creates a string with one Unicode character U+0080. When you convert this back to `NSData` with

```
NSData *d1 = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

then `d1` will contain the bytes `0xC2 0x80` (which is the UTF-8 for U+0080). But

```
NSData *d2 = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

does also not work (`d2 = nil`), because the string cannot be converted to 7-bit
ASCII.

So you should either

- store the encrypted data as "Binary Data" in Core Data, or
- store the encrypted data as String, but choose a different conversion strategy,
  for example Base64.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i knew that the conversions were wrong but since i am new to iphone i couldnt know the ways to fix it. I solved the problem using both ways but i guess the first one (store as binary data) is the most appropriate for this situation..

Comment: @GeorgeNikolaides: Yes, storing as binary data is the better way, that's why I put it first on the possible solutions list.